Как текст сделать маркером?
Хочу сделать Skeleton для текста как в телеграмме когда вы переводите из англ на русский. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при добавление background к тегу p, он не становится маркировочным, а выделяет сразу весь блок. Как это решить?

<p>
  &nbsp;It’s getting warmer in Dubai, and my friends are leaving for fancy places like the south of France. As a French citizen, I agree that France is the best holiday destination 
  <br>
  <br>
  &nbsp;As the Telegram CEO though, I don’t take holidays. Instead, I keep working while meeting our users from unusual locations. This summer I’ve decided to check out Central Asia to see what life is like there, study how people use Telegram and what their digital needs are 
  <br>
  <br>
  &nbsp;I will keep you posted in this channel about my discoveries 
</p>

body {
  max-width: 450px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}


Я имею ввиду, выделить каждую строку внутри тега p без изменений html. Исключительно css

т.е. без тега mark в html?

"... он не становится маркировочным..." От эт аще нипанятна :-(

Если вам принципиально, чтобы элемент <p> был inline-block, то оберните внутри него текст в <span> и задайте background-color ему. А так, можно и для <p> указать свойство display: inline;. Одним словом, чтобы добиться желаемого эффекта, нужен строчный элемент

Если вдруг вам подойдет такой вариант: https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/LYozrYK

Darinka, да, это оно. Но я написал, что без изменений html, тк ту структуру которую я показал, она идет из базы

И искать абзацы чтобы кинуть в базу, для меня это лютый бред :)

Deonis, спасибо, сработало :)

Можна так сделать. Хотя правильнее б было распарсить перед отображением текст и проставить нужные теги.


p {
  background-color: #f00;
}

br {
  content: "" !important;
  display: block !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
}
<p>
  &nbsp;It’s getting warmer in Dubai, and my friends are leaving for fancy places like the south of France. As a French citizen, I agree that France is the best holiday destination 
  <br>
  <br>
  &nbsp;As the Telegram CEO though, I don’t take holidays. Instead, I keep working while meeting our users from unusual locations. This summer I’ve decided to check out Central Asia to see what life is like there, study how people use Telegram and what their digital needs are 
  <br>
  <br>
  &nbsp;I will keep you posted in this channel about my discoveries 
</p>




спасибо, тоже отличный вариант :)
